# How can I get type names and member TypeObjects from a ts.TypeObject?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-compiler-api

I'm working with a TypeScript compiler to perform some code generation. This is my first time working with the compiler API directly.

With some ugly narrowing below (improvement of which I will save for another question), I'm able to get a `ts.TypeObject` from a `FirstStatement`. However, I'm unsure how I can use this object to examine its type.

I need to be able to do two things with this type object (or other):

1. Extract the top-level type name.
2. Recursively extract members' type names down to primitives.

```js
import ts from “typescript”;

// get program, checker, and sources
const program = ts.createProgram([__filename], {});
const checker = program.getTypeChecker();
const sources = program.getSourceFiles();

// iterate through sources
sources.forEach((source)=>{
    if(source.fileName === __filename){ // find this file
        ts.forEachChild(source, (node)=>{
            if(ts.SyntaxKind[node.kind] === "FirstStatement"){ // find first statements
                ts.forEachChild(node, (child)=>{
                    if(!(child as any).declarations) return;
                    const dec = (child as any).declarations[0]; // get the first declaration
                    if(dec && dec.symbol) console.log(checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(dec.symbol, node))
                }); // get the type of the symbol
            }
        })
    }
});
```

How can I do this? Or, in the least, where should I be looking in the docs for these kinds of questions?

Comment: Okay, so I remember first learning a few different languages, and things being a bit more that just rough. To point you in the right directoion I am gonna straight with you. Its not possible to answer your question because it doesn't really make sense to do what ever it is your trying to do. Your putting way to much emphasis on types, while at the same time, your not typing anything (by typing I mean type-annotating). My guess is that you read the narrowing section in the TS docs, and you misinterpreted its meaning.

Comment: One example of what I am trying to explain, is the typechecker that you wrote. You shouldn't be writing a typ-checker, TSC should to the type checking.

Comment: Another example is that you havn't any types added to anything, so its not clear what it is your trying to narrow? And your the first person I have ever seen who wound up in narrowing-hell! (Like callback-hell, but for narrowing)

Comment: My suggestion is that you work more on your JavaScript before you start trying to write JS with a type-system. I really think that, that is good advice for you. Also, type-script has been sort-of easy for me to learn, because I already new JS plus I knew Java & C++ two which are two typed languages. I really don't think typescript is a good language for anyone to learn about types with. It makes far more sense to learn a **TRUE** "statically-typed-compiled language" before using a language that adds a type system to a language that is fundamentally a dynamically typed language.

Comment: @jD3V I believe you may have misunderstood. I’m not trying to learn TypeScript. I am trying to work with the TypeScript AST (produced by the compiler API) to generate analogous code in another language according to a very strict lexicon.

Comment: @jD3V But, the question is more of a “where is the documentation for the TypeObjects” because the commenting in the source is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I was just feeling a bit too lazy when I wrote this. There is an example in the [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#using-the-type-checker).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).